# express js, mysql query backend, get request

Tags: mysql, express, backend, get-request

I'm using insomnia to send get request to my backend but there's no error and data even there are data's in it, just a empty bracket []

```
router.get("/", getAnswers);

export const getAnswers = (req, res) => {
  const q =
    "SELECT a.*, u.id AS user_id, username, image FROM answers AS a JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = a.user_id) WHERE a.question_id = ? ORDER BY a.created_date DESC";

  db.query(q, [req.query.question_id], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    return res.status(200).json(data);
  });
};
```

**i want to get data's like **

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "desc": "test",
  "user_id":"1"
 },
 {
  etc...
 }
]
```

**just like that.**

Comment: Well, you need to do some debugging to determine if this is a javascript or an sql problem.